# How to run multiple stages on the same node with declarative Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Goal**
Run multiple stages of a declarative Jenkins pipeline on the same node.

**Setup**
This is just a minimal example to show the problem. There are 2 Windows nodes "windows-slave1" and "windows-slave2" both labeled with the label "windows".

NOTE: My real Jenkinsfile cannot use a global agent because there are groups of stages that require to run on different nodes (e.g. Windows vs. Linux).

**Expected Behaviour**
Jenkins selects one of the nodes in "Stage 1" based on the label and uses the same node in "Stage 2" because the variable *windowsNode* was updated to the node selected in "Stage 1".

**Actual Behaviour**
"Stage 2" sometimes runs on the same and sometimes on a different node than "Stage 1". See the output below.

**Jenkinsfile**

```groovy
#!groovy

windowsNode = 'windows'

pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1') {
      agent {
        label windowsNode
      }
      steps {
        script {
          // all subsequent steps should be run on the same windows node
          windowsNode = NODE_NAME
        }
        echo "windowsNode: $windowsNode, NODE_NAME: $NODE_NAME"
      }
    }
    stage('Stage 2') {
      agent {
        label windowsNode
      }
      steps {
        echo "windowsNode: $windowsNode, NODE_NAME: $NODE_NAME"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage 1)
[Pipeline] node
Running on windows-slave2 in C:\Jenkins\workspace\test-agent-allocation@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
windowsNode: windows-slave2, NODE_NAME: windows-slave2
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage 2)
[Pipeline] node
Running on windows-slave1 in C:\Jenkins\workspace\test-agent-allocation
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
windowsNode: windows-slave2, NODE_NAME: windows-slave1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Any ideas what's wrong with the setup? I guess it's how the Jenkinsfile is parsed and executed.

Other suggestions? Maybe there is a Jenkins API to select a node based on the "windows" label when setting *windowsNode* initially.

Comment: Your stage 2 is not picking up the renamed variable. If you change `windowsNode = 'windows'` to `windowsNode = 'asdf'` then you should see a "There are no nodes with the label ‘asdf’" error, meaning your stage 2 is still running `label 'windows'` and not `label 'windows-slave2'`.

Comment: However, I tried `stage("Stage 2" ) { environment { someVariable = "$windowsNode" } agent { label env.someVariable } ..` and although it allocates a node and gives no "missing property" errors (meaning `agent` at least is aware that someVariable exists), it does NOT work.  If I print the value of `env.someVariable` it is the node name, so although it can see the correct `windowsNode` variable, I suspect that `someVariable` is in some blank state in the `agent` directive causing it to run something like `agent label ''` instead of `agent label 'windows-slave2'`.

Comment: I also tried `environment { someVariable = "\'$windowsNode\'" }` which makes the variable `'windows-slave2'` instead of just `windows-slave2`, but it still randomly allocates between my two test nodes (still no errors about the variable or label name though).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since version 1.3 of Declarative Pipeline plugin, this is officially supported.
It's officially called "Sequential Stages".

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage("check code style") {
            agent {
                docker "code-style-check-image"
            }
            steps {
                sh "./check-code-style.sh"
            }
        }

        stage("build and test the project") {
            agent {
                docker "build-tools-image"
            }
            stages {
               stage("build") {
                   steps {
                       sh "./build.sh"
                   }
               }
               stage("test") {
                   steps {
                       sh "./test.sh"
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Official announcement here: https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/

Comment: Nice feature, but what you use do if you have to allocate 2 separate nodes in the stages sequence:
stage1 - nodeA
stage2 - nodeB
stage3 - nodeA
stage4 - nodeA
?
Would you it be ok to save NODE_NAME into variables nodeA|B  and in stage 3 and 4 use that in agent {node nodeA|B} ?

Comment: I get a syntax error if I try to do this when the sequential block is itself part of a parallel stage. I see a similar complaint in the issue that originated this development. It's not at all uncommon but whoever implemented the feature seems not to have thought of it. If there is a way to make it work, I'll be glad to hear. As it is, I had to have recourse to a variable defined in pipeline enviroment, set in a script block in the 1st seq stage and write/read it without the env. prefix.

Comment: what about the post stage? does this apply to that as well?

Answer (score 12):

You could define stages inside a script block. Those stages are kind of sub-stages of a parent stage running in a given agent. That was the approach that I had to use in a similar use case than yours.

```groovy
#!groovy

windowsNode = 'windows'

pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Stage A') {
      agent {
        label windowsNode
      }
      steps {
        script {

          stage('Stage 1') {        
            windowsNode = NODE_NAME
            echo "windowsNode: $windowsNode, NODE_NAME: $NODE_NAME"
          }

          stage('Stage 2') {
            echo "windowsNode: $windowsNode, NODE_NAME: $NODE_NAME"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the slave also have two executors and I've blocked the two executors for this job, Is it possible to use parallel stages with this approach?

Answer (score 5):

I have found that this works as you would expect

```
#!groovy

windowsNode = 'windows'

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                node(windowsNode) {
                    script {
                        // all subsequent steps should be run on the same windows node
                        windowsNode = NODE_NAME
                    }
                    echo "windowsNode: $windowsNode, NODE_NAME: $NODE_NAME"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Stage 2') {
            steps {
                node(windowsNode) {
                    echo "windowsNode: $windowsNode, NODE_NAME: $NODE_NAME"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -8):

replace `agent none` with `agent any`

Comment: This will not help. Using `agent any` means that if an agent is not provided in a `step` then it will try to run on `any` available node. OP wants the steps to run on specific nodes.

Comment: That is not correct, specifying an agent at the start of the pipeline allocates an agent for the whole script.