# Run downstream jobs on same executor?

Tags: jenkins

I am working on tests of embedded devices.

We have a device farm where several types of devices (say A, B and C), with many instances each (A1..A10, B1..B10, C1..C10), are available for remote testing. Each device is connected to a Jenkins node (with label 'A', 'B' or 'C'). So far, if we wanted to test systems of devices (A, B and C working together), they were connected to many Jenkins nodes ("multi-node setup") which had to be addressed individually.

Now we would like to replace these with single-node setups (all embedded devices A, B, C controlled by the same node). The current job structure involved reserving all nodes from a given multi-node setup on a high level and then calling different jobs one by one which then run on the respective node.

For reasons of maintainability and clear responsibility, I would like to retain the structure of several sub-jobs for given test.

My problem is now that the top-level job chooses any of the single-node setups, but of course all downstream sub-jobs need to run on that exact instance, which I can assure by [passing the `NODE_NAME` of the top-level job as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281371/using-the-same-node-on-all-downstream-jobs-in-a-jenkins-pipeline). Unfortunately, since I should never have two (top-level) jobs running on a same instance in parallel, I can only define one executor per node. Which, in turn, means that a downstream job supposed to run on the same node as the top-level job will always wait for the executor to become available infinitely.

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to allow a downstream job to "reuse" an executor from an upstream job?

I am perfectly ok with "No, there isn't", but it would make managing our tests easier if there were. Otherwise I'll just have to roll all jobs into one big one.

Comment: Are you using pipeline jobs or freestyle? in addition why not run the first job, trigger the second one without waiting, the first will finish, second starts and so on?

Comment: Pipeline. If there is a queue of jobs for this type of node, then another job may snatch up the same instance that the first job just freed.