# How to overwrite node in jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to save my jenkins scripts in git repo. When a build is triggered on jenkins master, it checks out the desired script such as file1.groovy which looks like the following.

```
node {
  sh "echo hello"
}
```

My question is how to overwrite that node to node('agent1') at run time. Is it possible? I'm happy to look at other solutions as well. Apparently I can hardcode node('agent1') in file1.groovy but I don't want to expose that in the script.

Comment: May be you are looking for something like this. [Can I assign a node dynamically within an iterative loop in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66457551/can-i-assign-a-node-dynamically-within-an-iterative-loop-in-jenkins)

Comment: You could parameterize the job that is triggered on jenkins master and resolve its parameter in the pipeline script. `node("${env.PARAM}") { sh "echo hello" }` assuming the parameter is a string parameter named `PARAM` with default value `agent1`.